# Horizontal alignment to margins while not losing vertical alignment

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

In HTML, I have two elements, one with text and one containing a couple of buttons.

[image]

Instead of touching in the middle, I want them spaced to align to the left and right margins. So I want my text aligned to the left margin, and my buttons aligned to the right margin, **without losing their vertical alignment as is**.

I also happen to be using Bootstrap 3.

When I use `pull-left`/`pull-right`, `float:left`/`float:right`, or `align="left"`/`align="right"`, I get a change in the vertical alignment of these two elements.

Paired down code looks like this essentially:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px">
    Delete dashboard?
    <button class="btn btn-secondary cancel">
        Cancel
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete
    </button>
</div>
```

What is the the most straightforward way to align these items to the left and right margins? I can do it with a table, but is that not the ideal way?

[![A modal example][2]][2]

Comment: Post your code please and replicate what you have in the screenshot currently.

Comment: Need to see the code

Comment: I added a code example. Pretty simple really. The challenge is to keep the left and right side elements vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I would use a flex layout. The key in a flex `row` is to use `justify-content: space-between` to push 2 children in the row to the far edges. Then `align-items` on the parent will set the vertical alignment.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.bot {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex col">
  <div>
    <h1>confirm</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flex bot">
    <p>delete dashboard</p>
    <div>
      <button>cancel</button>
      <button>delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Dashboard</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">Cancel Delete</div>
</div>
```

This will split your area in two columns, where all content of the right column will be aligned right, without affecting the CSS of the elements itself.